# Projection on the Type in an <Any> mapping in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, any

Given the class :

```
public class VotingResult : DomainEntity
{
    public const string DefaultTag = "overall";

    public VotingResult()
    {
        Dimension = DefaultTag;
    }

    public virtual DomainEntity Item { get; set; }

    public virtual String Dimension { get; set; }

    public virtual double Value { get; set; }

    public virtual int VoteCount { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}

   }
```

And the mapping

```
public sealed class VotingResultMap : ClassMap<VotingResult>
{
    private VotingResultMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Option);
        Map(x => x.Dimension);
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
        Map(x => x.Value);
        Map(x => x.VoteCount);
        ReferencesAny(x => x.Item).AddMetaValues(); // extension method to add discriminators
    }
}
```

Is there any way to project VotingResult.Item.GetType(), either through Linq or HQL ("Select r.class from VotingResult" does not seem to work. There are some nasty tricks i can use, but i need to be able to easily flatten the reference into a type and id - ideally using Linq or AliasToBeanResultTransformer.

For the record, inheritance mapping for DomainEntity subclasses are Table Per Class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ you can project after loading

```
var results = Session.Query<VotingResult>()
    .Where( ...)
    .Include(result => result.Item)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(result => new
    {
        ItemType = result.Item.GetType().Name,
        ItemId = result.Item.Id
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out and report back.